# What does %$ mean in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a script that has a number of `%$`'s in it and despite a bunch of searching I haven't been able to find what they mean. Could someone please help me out?

Note:
Apologies if this is a naïve question I'm not a perl dev I've just been asked to recreate a perl script in python. I have only very basic knowledge of the language.

Comment: It is the way of hash dereferencing in Perl. See [here](https://perlmaven.com/dereference-hash-array) for more details.

Comment: The Python equivalent of `%$hash` is `dict`. In Python, you always deal with dictionaries through a reference. That's not the case in Perl. Unlike Python, Perl has dictionary variables. Like Python, you can have reference to dictionaries in Perl. If you're actually asking about `%$ref` (short for `%{ $ref }`), then you have such a reference, and you are accessing the referenced hash.

Comment: Well, it could also be `len(dict)` or `get_list_of_keys_and_values(dict)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to a hash (say in a variable called `$hash_ref`) then you put a `%` in front of it to dereference the hash reference and get back to the actual hash - `%$hash_ref`.

See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) for a tutorial on references in Perl.

For future reference, it would be easier to help you if you included some samples of the actual code you are asking about.